# Any privacy considerations regarding allowing inbound connections for a Tor full node?

Tags: network, privacy, full-node, tor

I wanted to know if there's any privacy considerations to take into account when opening the bitcoin ports on the router for a bitcoin node.

I'm using `-onlynet=onion` in the bitcoin.conf file and I did not modify any tor config file.

I also wonder if a remote port scan can detect I have a bitcoin port open in the router and whether changing to a random port would help privacy. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running -onlynet=onion, there is no need to open any router ports. Perhaps I misunderstand your question.

If your chain state is caught up, and bitcoind+Tor is properly configured, you should be serving data to other nodes, even behind an otherwise locked-down home router.

What result do you get when running

```
$ bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo | grep true
```

Comment: I can connect to peers but I have no inbound connections. so it seems I need to open router ports hence my question.

Comment: You definitely do not need open any router ports--that would defeat the purpose of Tor routing. I run my full node over Tor only, behind a locked down router with no external ports exposed. These are the steps I used for Tor config: https://medium.com/@lopp/how-to-run-bitcoin-as-a-tor-hidden-service-on-ubuntu-cff52d543756

Comment: @bg thank you. following that guide I am now able to have inbound connections without having to open any router ports with my tor full node.